# AppBar tabs on click listener

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I have a tabbed activity with fragments.

The number of tabs is generate from the default code bellow:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 6;
        }
    }
```

I have add icons on my tabs with the code bellow:

```
private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.web,
            R.drawable.social,
            R.drawable.contact,
            R.drawable.partners,
            R.drawable.exclusivevideo,
            R.drawable.jobifyblack
    };
```

And inside onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) i am using the code bellow:

```
// primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        //Add icons on tabs
        final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabIcons[4]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(5).setIcon(tabIcons[5]);
```

By default all tabs are generated inside AppBarLayout.

Now the only thing that i want is how to trigger a click on last tab to open a new activity and do not open fragment inside container.

I tried a lot of examples without any luck!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/

Try this example if you are not looking this please comment

Comment: Hello there... this example that you provided is different from mine.. it extends TabActivity, mine is generated as default from android studio template to use fragments.. Also my project can't resolve TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();